# NHibernate exception on query

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm getting a mapping exception doing the most basic query.
This is my domain class:

```
public class Project
{
    public virtual string PK { get; set; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the mapping class:

```
public class ProjectMap :ClassMap<Project>
{
    public ProjectMap()
    {
        Table("PROJECTS");
        Id(x => x.PK, "PK");
        Map(x => x.Id, "ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
        Map(x => x.Description, "DESCRIPTION");
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
public ISessionFactory SessionFactory
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql().ConnectionString(c => c.Is("data source=" + path)))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Project>())
        .BuildSessionFactory();

}
```

And query:
IList project;

```
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Project");
    project = query.List<Project>();
}
```

I'm getting the exception on the query line:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Project is not mapped [from Project]
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SessionFactoryHelperExtensions.RequireClassPersister(String name)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElementFactory.AddFromElement()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromClause.AddFromElement(String path, IASTNode alias)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromElement()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromElementList()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromClause()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.unionedQuery()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.query()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectStatement()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.statement()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Analyze(HqlParseEngine parser, String collectionRole)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.Compile(IDictionary`2 replacements, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString)
```

I assume something is wrong with my query.

Comment: Is your ProjectMap class in the same assembly as the Project class?

Comment: Off topic, but what's the difference between PK and ID?

Comment: No. ProjectMap class is in the DatabaseServer assembly. Project class is in the domain assembly. The DatabaseServer assembly has a reference to the domain assembly.

Comment: PK is the database key. ID is the application key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yoav the problem is that you need to specify the assembly where your mapping files are, not where your Entities are. Change the call to

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ProjectMap>())
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I was wondering where the ProjectMap was referenced. BTW - This means I have to add a line for each ClassMap, or once is enough (all ClassMaps will be in the same assemply)?

Comment: @Yoav, AddFromAssemblyOf method will go through and map all the ClassMaps for you in one go.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your mapping class is actually executed. You can do that by placing break points inside the ProjectMap class and then debugging to ensure it is executed.

```
using (ISession Session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    DetachedCriteria Filter = DetachedCriteria.For<Project>();
    var Projects = Filter.GetExecutableCriteria(Session).List<Project>();
}
```

Try using DetachedCriteria to ensure your query is not miss spelled ... I usually use the DetachedCriteria for querying because then I don't need to know the Hql.

Comment: Any reason for using DetachedCriteria vs a regular Criteria?

Comment: Can you tell me which namespace to use for DetachedCriteria?

Comment: It comes from NHibernate.Criterion. I don't have a particular reason for using it except it's a well known API and easy to use. It also can be created without a session, so in reality it's just a wrapper around the ICriteria interface.